# Pytorch geometric: how to explain the input in the below code-snippet?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, data-science, pytorch-geometric

I am reading PyTorch geometric documentation at https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/introduction.html

On this page, there is a code snippet:

```
import torch
from torch_geometric.data import Data

edge_index = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 1, 2],
                           [1, 0, 2, 1]], dtype=torch.long)
x = torch.tensor([[-1], [0], [1]], dtype=torch.float)

data = Data(x=x, edge_index=edge_index)
```

The output of the last line from the above code snippet is:

```
Data(edge_index=[2, 4], x=[3, 1])
```

How are the `edge_index` 2 and 4? If I understand correctly there are four edges being defined with an index starting from 0. Is this assumption wrong? Also, what does `x =[3, 1]` mean?

`Data` is a class, so I won't expect it to return anything. Class definition is here: https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/data.html . I read the documentation. `x` should be Node feature matrix and `edge_index` should be graph connectivity. But I don't understand the console output that I cross-checked in the jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I have got the understanding of the output `Data(edge_index=[2, 4], x=[3, 1])`. Here [2,4] are dimensions of `edge_index` and [3,1] are dimensions of `x`. But please, anyone correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That is exactly the correct interpretation of the output. You have 4 edges (or two undirected) and for each of the 3 nodes you have a 1-dimensional features, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70565788).