# What are the elements from a data in Pytorch Geometric?

Tags: pytorch, generator, pytorch-geometric

I am studying on GNN, and to code :

[Pytorch Geometric Introduction Code](https://colab.research.google.com/github/AntonioLonga/PytorchGeometricTutorial/blob/main/Tutorial1/Tutorial1.ipynb) from [Pytorch Geometric Tutorial](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/colabs.html)

```
import torch_geometric
from torch_geometric.datasets import Planetoid
dataset = Planetoid(root="tutorial1",name= "Cora")
data = dataset[0]
print(data)
```

> ```
> Data(x=[2708, 1433], edge_index=[2, 10556], y=[2708], train_mask=[2708], val_mask=[2708], test_mask=[2708])
> ```

```
##############(I omitted my neural network and train(), which are not related to my question)########

def test():
    model.eval()
    logits, accs = model(), []
    for _, mask in data('train_mask', 'val_mask', 'test_mask'):
        pred = logits[mask].max(1)[1]
        acc = pred.eq(data.y[mask]).sum().item() / mask.sum().item()
        accs.append(acc)
    return accs
```

What I am curious is that

```
  for_, mask in data('train_mask', 'val_mask', 'test_mask):
```

Because I don't understand what data('train_mask', 'val_mask', 'test_mask) is. The result is

```
<generator object Data.__call__ at 0x7f617c8498d0>
```

So I don't get what it is. I read some documentations of generator, but then how can I see what the elements are?

Answer (score 1):

The `data` object you retrieve from the `Planetoid` dataset is a single graph. You have the following attributes:

- `x` the node features, hence it's dimension is number of nodes (2703) times feature dimension (1433)
- `edge_index` the edge list
- `y` the "ground truth"/class labels or in that specific case the classification of the papers. Hence, it's shape is the number of nodes.
- The three masks: `train_mask`, `val_mask`, `test_mask`. If I access them via `data.train_mask`, it gives me a boolean tensor with the length = number of nodes. This is the "default split" of the dataset. They should be disjoint and if `True` the respective node is in that set.